Why is my intended target not showing up in the 'Track To' constraint list?
I am trying to get my camera to follow my character's animation. The character has a bone named "fx_damage_02", and with other characters from the same source, that bone shows up in the 'Track To' constraint list as an available target.  Not so with this character.  How do I get the bone to show up in the list?
Here's the blend file:
Blend file
If you download that file, please ignore the cube named "Camera focal point". I was trying something, and it didn't work.

you have first to choose "Armature" in track to, then a new field will appear, where you can select your bone.


I cannot believe how simple that was.  Thanks so much!  That's been really derailing my work for a long time now.
